# How to sort Django QuerySet output by date?

Tags: python, django

I have data like this:

Data Created by this query:

```
data = Post.objects.filter(post_by=UserID).
       values_list('posted_date_time','post_id')
       .union(post_wishlist.objects.filter(user_id=UserID)
       .values_list('added_date_time', 'post_id'))
```

Can i make it better query where it provide shorted data according to date.

Output

```
<QuerySet [(datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 14, 20, 4, 58, 104805, tzinfo=<UTC>), UUID('b15be3c1-3f70-4ccb-af08-dba385f883a1')), 
          (datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 12, 18, 42, 38, 675120, tzinfo=<UTC>), UUID('f2ea2ad0-f228-43d7-823a-c824a041feb2')), 
          (datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 12, 17, 46, 38, 479890, tzinfo=<UTC>), UUID('16c66e9b-0cbf-4b6d-b848-78cf771f522c')),
          (datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 21, 20, 17, 15, 785171, tzinfo=<UTC>), UUID ('a169afcf-267b-4212-97e5-6221595ab107')),
          (datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 15, 7, 33, 34, 136331, tzinfo=<UTC>), UUID('9aac6b06-6622-4587-9956-5b517aaa11e8')),
          (datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 18, 16, 11, 49, 134458, tzinfo=<UTC>), UUID('00271b56-9ff7-4f9d-b9c0-2592ca9436d2')), 
          (datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 21, 21, 3, 53, 528261, tzinfo=<UTC>), UUID('df0d8905-5377-4b8d-99d9-eba644273eaa')),
          (datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 21, 21, 4, 6, 256957, tzinfo=<UTC>), UUID('c339d797-f37d-48ff-94a6-e6d1510e23cc')), 
          (datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 18, 17, 10, 18, 388505, tzinfo=<UTC>), UUID('00271b56-9ff7-4f9d-b9c0-2592ca9436d2'))]>
```

In the QuerySet i've multiple datetime instance with UUID,

I created this data using 2 different model and both model have different datetime field name, so i think we can't use CHAIN.

**Here I want to sort according to datetime**

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: while querying you can specify `order_by('datetime_fieldname')`

Comment: This data comes from 2 different table

Comment: You can sort it in Python using `sorted`. I'll write a detailed answer

Comment: Many thanks i'm waiting for your response

Comment: You should really post the code that generated this data structure: How did you manage to get a Queryset from two models?

Comment: I updated my questions please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a single model, you can always go for [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) which is the best approach.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

ModelA.objects.order_by("timestamp")
```

If you have multiple models, that have similar data (not necessarily fields), you can still use `order_by`.

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)


ModelA.objects.values("timestamp").union(
    ModelB.objects.annotate(timestamp=F("created")).values("timestamp")
).order_by("timestamp").values("timestamp")
```

It's important that the number of fields in both queries is exactly the same, and corresponding fields in the queries are of the same data type. (I might have used `.values()` too many times here. I can't recall the syntax at the top of my head.)

This, of course, is not as readable as [sorting it in python](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sorting.html).

```
data_a = ModelA.objects.values("timestamp")
data_b = ModelB.objects.annotate(timestamp=F("created")).values("timestamp")

final_data = sorted(data_a + data_b, key=lambda x: x["timestamp"])
```

Notice that in both cases, I've annotated and added a field called `timestamp` in the second model to match the name in the first. It just makes things easier.

The `order_by` has two advantages over the python `sorted`

1. It's much faster in most cases as it happens at the DB which is
   optimized to handle such operations.
2. It allows you to continue doing query manipulation. For example, if you want
   the lastest 10 results, you can `.order_by("-timestamp")[10]`, but
   with Python, you would have to fetch all the data and then discard
   most of it. This can be super expensive and wasteful when you're
   dealing with large data sets.

Comment: in both model i have createdDate fields name but in different name, How can i manage to get sort?

Comment: How can i get 2 values.
here values("timestamp") i want to get 2 values.

Comment: The annotate should handle the different names...   If you want multiple values just include them in `.values(field1, field2, field3, ...)` Just make sure field1 in both queries are of the same type